# Chrome msi installer change directory

Tags: google-chrome, windows-installer, silent-installer

I'm trying to install chrome silently but I can't find the parameter to change the installation directory.

I'm running this:

```
\MSIEXEC.EXE /i GoogleChromeStandaloneEnterprise.msi TARGETDIR="D:\CHROME\" /qb /l*v D:chrome.txt
```

But all the time it installs the program in the default path.

I have tried the following parameters with the same result always:

```
APPLICATIONFOLDER="D:\CHROME\"

INSTALLDIR="D:\CHROME\"
```

Someone knows how to change the installation path?

Thanks a lot for the time.

Comment: It looks like the MSI here is a wrapper for an exe-based installer run via a custom action. Hence the normal MSI properties will not take effect. The [Chrome Browser Deployment Guide](https://support.google.com/chrome/a/answer/3115278) (a link you already have I guess) can help manage settings, but it looks like changing the installation directory isn't really supported properly? I am not sure. Maybe try the [ITNinja Package Tip Database](https://www.itninja.com/software-library/company/google). And maybe serverfault.com or similar.

Comment: Other approach would be to package the application again, using so called the "Repackaging process". This way you will have full acess to installed resources and be able to control where the application is getting installed.